# How to loop twice to insert different values into 2 different stacks

Tags: c++, stack, do-while

I am trying to insert into 2 stacks but for some reason when I run the program the first loop runs and then skips the second loop.

```
do  
{
    cout<<"enter data: ";
    cin>>data;
    cout<<data<<endl;
    if (cin.fail()){
        cin.clear(); 
        break; 
    }
    else{
        stack1.push(data);
    }
}while(cin.good()); 
//stack 2
do
{
    cout<<"enter data: ";
    cin>>data;
    cout<<data<<endl;
    if (cin.fail()){
        cin.clear(); 
        break;
    }
    else{
        stack2.push(data);
    }
}while(cin.good());
```

Comment: If `cin.good()` becomes false, it will never start the second loop. You could check for a specific input and go to the second loop when you read this

Comment: At the end of the first loop, cin.good() is false. Maybe try to make cin.good() false again before the second loop.

Comment: Why it would never enter the escond loop?, it is a do-while, it always make the first loop.

Comment: Try adding different debug info in the escond loop. Maybe is giving and error the escond cin for some reason. Or try to run your code in any debugger to step into the code.

Comment: @AsierSánchezRodríguez it will enter the second loop, but it will not input anything.

Comment: The user has no idea how, or in some cases no possibility, to stop entering data. Consider a more user-friendly input method.

Answer (score 1):

Because you never `break` out of the first loop once you've got valid data, you probably want something more like:

```
do  
{
    cout<<"enter data: ";
    cin>>data;
    cout<<data<<endl;
    if (cin.fail()){
        cin.clear(); 
    }
    else{
        stack1.push(data);
        break; 
    }
}while(cin.good());
```

Comment: That would just allow me to insert one item into the stack.

Comment: Ah, OK. Find the code a bit confusing :(  So you want to keep on entering items until the input fails.   Shouldn't you also fix `cin` if the `while` condition fails? And perhaps `flush` `cout` in the enter prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Try using both the push codes in the same loop itself

```
do
{
cout<<"enter data: ";
cin>>data;
cout<<data<<endl;
if (cin.fail()){
cin.clear();
break; 
}
else{
stack1.push(data);
stack2.push(data);
}
}while(cin.good());
```